# Java payment gateway library

Tags: java, payment-gateway

I'm looking for a Java payment gateway library similar to the Rails active_merchant or the libraries available on many other platforms.  I've been surprised that I've been unable to find one.  I'd like something that supports the major gateways and providers, like Paypal, Google, Amazon, and some direct merchant account providers like Authorize.net.

Does such a thing exist in the open source world?

Comment: Let's move this question to the right place http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: https://github.com/tranxactive/J2PAY OR
http://j2pay.org
kindly have a review of this library, we support multiple gateways and our list are expanding day by day, you are warmly welcome to contribute with us aswell

Answer (score 3):

[Stripe](https://stripe.com) has a Java library to accept credit cards without needing a merchant account: https://github.com/stripe/stripe-java

Check out the [documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/api?lang=java) and [FAQ](https://stripe.com/help/faq), and feel free to drop by our [chatroom](https://stripe.com/campfire) if you have more questions.

Comment: Just signed up with Stripe and took it for a test spin. For what it's worth, I'll never use anything else ever again.

Comment: It's a closed-source saas with a simple client API. So it's not a payment gateway lib similar to omnipay or payum (from PHP) or active_merchant (from Ruby).

Comment: check out J2pay https://github.com/tranxactive/J2PAY

Answer (score 1):

I found nice paypal library at sourceforge:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/paypal-nvp/