# Open payment gateway libraries for Java, Python, Ruby, Node.JS, and PHP

Tags: java, php, python, ruby, payment-gateway

I'm looking for generic and open source payment libraries that support many different payment processor APIs. In other words, I'd like to develop an application using a single payment processing API, but be able to easily switch between payment gateways, such as Authorize.Net, Payflow Pro, Braintree, PayPal, Google, Amazon, etc.

This question gives some [Java solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2242653/java-payment-gateway-library), but the suggestions all look horrible. Isn't there anything more like ActiveMerchant for Java? I really need a good Java solution, to the point of building my own if necessary. But I don't want to reinvent the wheel if it exists.

Are there any solutions for Python, Node.JS, or PHP?

Ideally, I'd like to find something similar to Ruby's [ActiveMerchant](http://www.activemerchant.org/), which looks exceptionally complete. Are there any other Ruby solutions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do any projects exist for PHP that is similar to ActiveMerchant for Ruby?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2768942/do-any-projects-exist-for-php-that-is-similar-to-activemerchant-for-ruby)

Comment: @John, thanks for pointing this out. I'll reference that question for PHP solutions. However, my question isn't specific to PHP and I'm still interested in solutions for other languages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I have seen done is just wrapping Active Merchant into a light weight web service which exposes a rest API that any of your languages can talk to. This was for a larger company that could properly lock down their networks though, so DYODD.

Comment: That's a great idea, can't believe I didn't already think of doing it. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can checkout [J2pay](https://github.com/tranxactive/J2PAY) its clean and its supported gateway list is continuously increasing.

Comment: j2pay support is amazing

Answer (score 3):

I created Paython: https://github.com/abunsen/Paython

Supports a few different processors:

1. Stripe
2. Authorize.net
3. First Data / Linkpoint
4. Innovative Gateway (from intuit)
5. Plugnpay
6. Samurai

Answer (score 2):

There's a python port of ActiveMerchant called [OpenMerch](http://github.com/afarnham/openmerch), which looks quite similar to the ActiveMerchant code.

Comment: nice, thanks for the pointer. I'll keep my eye on that project.

Answer (score 2):

There is [django-bursar](http://github.com/grengojbo/django-bursar) for use with django.

Answer (score 1):

I originally left Node.JS out of the list of server-side technologies, but I'm starting a project that is going to use it.  And I found what looks like a great payment gateway library for it. [Paynode](https://github.com/jamescarr/paynode) is similar to Ruby's ActiveMerchant, but in Javascript running in Node.JS. It supports Payflow Pro, Authorize.Net, Braintree, Chargify, etc.

Answer (score 1):

[omnipay](https://github.com/thephpleague/omnipay) is the best solution for PHP

Answer (score 0):

You can embed JRuby in your JVM and start using any ruby libraries you want!Same is valid for any other JVM languages!