# is there a multiple payment providers (paypal, ogone, ...) php module for use in a web app?

Tags: php, zend-framework, e-commerce, payment-gateway, payment-processing

We are building an ecommerce app where we want our users to pick out a (any provider we can make compatible with our app) payment provider. Up to today, we only support paypal and we have implemented this rather manually.

We are looking for some sort of a module (free or commercial) to easily plugin in more payment providers to let customers accept payments through them. Our customers would use this to accept payments for sales in their web shops.

Any ideas on such "modules"?
I know of the Zend_Payment module but that's not updated anymore or isn't out yet at all.
We run PHP in the Zend Framework if that matters.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Open payment gateway libraries for Java, Python, Ruby, and PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2870255/open-payment-gateway-libraries-for-java-python-ruby-and-php)

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

http://phpclasses.100pour100net.com/package/5213-PHP-Accept-payments-with-Paypal-Authorize-net-and-2CO.html

It process several major payment gateways.

Answer (score 1):

I've recently been struggling with the same issue and finally decided to make it on my own. In result I've done a standalone Zend module with pluggable payment gateway methods. This solution is described [here](http://lifeinide.com/post/2010-12-30-zend-multiplayment-gateway/).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be able to offer multiple gateways you should look at http://Spreedlycore.com It's not PHP (Ruby) but essentially is a single API that connects to around 30 gateways.

Answer (score 0):

There is extensive developer documentation from many payment providers to assist in writing scripts to handle transaction requests. Usually these will involve sending some request to your payment gateway provider and providing a callback url where update information about the given transaction can be sent. It should not be difficult to develop an appropriate module for the occasion in Zend and a controllerAction to handle the callback functionality.